# Android --> java.net.ProtocolException: OutputStream unavailable because request headers have already been sent

Tags: android, json, drupal, httpurlconnection

I am trying for post data(username and password in JSON format for login) from android application to php server - drupal cms website using HttpUrlConnection .
Here is my code , For login.
I am getting this response:

> java.net.ProtocolException: OutputStream unavailable because request
>   headers have already been sent!

I have searched on google & other stackoverflow questions but cant find any solution to my problem. So Please Help.

Thanks for listening.

```
   HttpURLConnection httpcon = null;
          int status = 0;

         try {
              httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("my URL here").openConnection()));
              httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
              httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
              httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");

               status = httpcon.getResponseCode();

               httpcon.getHeaderFields();
               System.out.println("===================>httpcon.getHeaderFields()"+httpcon.getHeaderFields());


        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


          try {
            httpcon.connect(); 
             byte[] outputBytes = "{'username':'uname','password':'pass'}".getBytes("UTF-8");

             OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
              os.write(outputBytes);




              os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `httpcon.getResponseCode()` and `httpcon.getHeaderFields()` in the first part of your code. As mentioned in the javadoc for [`HttpUrlConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields%28%29), this causes the HTTP request to be executed. This makes sense, because to read the response header fields you need a response, and to get a response you have to issue the request.

You then do the output stream stuff, which fails because the request has already been sent.

To make this work, you need to re-order your code so that all the request stuff is set up before you access the response stuff. Something along these lines:

```
byte[] outputBytes = "{'username':'uname','password':'pass'}".getBytes("UTF-8");
try {
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("my URL here").openConnection()));

    //prepare the request
    httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpcon.connect(); // May not be needed
    OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
    os.write(outputBytes);

    //get the response
    status = httpcon.getResponseCode();
    httpcon.getHeaderFields();
    System.out.println("===================>httpcon.getHeaderFields()"+httpcon.getHeaderFields());
} //catch block left out
```